# Find most occurred character in a String

Tags: java, string

I have this code:

```
public char charCounter(String input){
ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (Character c : input.toCharArray()) {
list.add(c);
```

There is a way to find a character most frequent in input String without to use the HashMap?

I tried to use:

```
int max = Collections.max(list.values())
```

but I can't.

Could help me someone?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you against  HashMap?

Comment: What does _most_ character mean?

Comment: most occurred character I think.

Comment: @MouseEvent: because the same problem I solved before and my teacher prefers that I use pure ArrayList.

Comment: If the character set is small (e.g. ASCII), you can use an `int[]` of occurance counters.

Comment: @Thilo: do you suggest to create an array 'value' and to put inside: value[input.charAt(c) -97]++; ?

Comment: @Clash: Yes. And you don't need to bother with the -97.

Comment: Although the OP had a constraint, the wide variety of answers will serve future visitors better without it. Edited title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ArrayList` is a requirement: After you built your ArrayList make a loop again over characters from input and use

`Collections.frequency(list, c)`

to get a number of each character occurrences which you will put into max if max is smaller.

PS. to make it more "smart" :-) you can create a `Set<Character>` in parallel with your `list` to have distinct characters from your input, and then loop through that set to get `Collections.frequency(list, c)`.

Or you can remove tested character from list by using `removeAll` method only, if you do not need your `list` anymore - at the end it will be empty.

UPDATED - working code - there are 2 variations with removeAll usage - one for first most character and second for last if there are more than 2 characters with the same number of occurrences. As long as you created your `list` inside the method and need only most Character returned there is no reason to keep `list` unchanged. It is gone at the end of method anyway.

*note:* (I made them static only because for testing I used main - you do not need to do that) - pick one :

```
    public static void main(String... args) {

    String input = "This is a simple test string+++++";

    System.out.println("charCounterV1First: first most Character: "
            + charCounterV1First(input));
    System.out.println("charCounterV1Last: last most Character: "
            + charCounterV1Last(input));

}

public static char charCounterV1First(String input) {
    ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (Character c : input.toCharArray()) {
        list.add(c);
    }

    int max = 0;
    Character mostChar = null;
    ArrayList<Character> remList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    while (list.size() > 0) {
        Character nextChar = list.get(0);
        int count = Collections.frequency(list, nextChar);
        if (count > max) {
            max = count;
            mostChar = nextChar;
        }
        remList.clear();
        remList.add(nextChar);
        list.removeAll(remList);
    }
    return mostChar;
}

public static char charCounterV1Last(String input) {
    ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (Character c : input.toCharArray()) {
        list.add(c);
    }

    int max = 0;
    Character mostChar = null;
    ArrayList<Character> remList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    while (list.size() > 0) {
        Character nextChar = list.get(0);
        int count = Collections.frequency(list, nextChar);
        if (count >= max) {
            max = count;
            mostChar = nextChar;
        }
        remList.clear();
        remList.add(nextChar);
        list.removeAll(remList);
    }
    return mostChar;
}
```

Comment: like this:
ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (Character c : input.toCharArray()) {
list.add(c);

Comment: like this:
'ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (Character c : input.toCharArray()) {
list.add(c); Collections.frequency(list, c);' after that how I could return the max character in use? Thanks

Comment: thank you for your code. I don't want bored you but at the moment I have a little problem with the 'return' instruction because the method was: public char charCounter(String input), and I need to close the circle of the method with a return.

Comment: What is a problem? use `return mostChar.charValue();` after all done.

Comment: and yes as @Anton pointed it is possible to have more than one characters with the same max occurrence. Both examples return first.if you'd like last one: just change ` if (count > max)` to ` if (count >= max)`. If you need all of them then method must return Array or List of Characters.

Comment: sorry Vadim I'm in deep confusion because l'm not able to make run the code, I have always mistake by return or by output. Please could you post the complete method unite with my first code? Thank you

Comment: I just wrote that "code" right here in site not in real working Java. I'll update it with real code a little later.

Comment: thank you very much. A last thing: If I want to have the most character present in the string but in alphabetic order. I mean if the string is 'ssaasa' I prefer to see the 'a' and not the 's', on which variables I can operate?

Comment: I put Collection.sort(list); into while loop before Character nextChar =list.get(0);

Comment: Yes. you are right, but there can be more conditions you need check. As example if input is not a word, but some phrases it is very likely  that most Character will be blank space (ASCII code 32). But you can improve your code as you need. Just check Character class methods there are many easy checks. Like `Character.isLetterOrDigit` and so on... Good luck!

Comment: you're very kind. Thank you for your help, I hope to meet you again. Salute :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
public char charCounter(String input){
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    int max = 0;
    int diff;
    char maxChar = '\0'; // in case it's an empty string, ignore if you don't understand
    for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
         diff = input.length() - input.replace("" + c, "").length();
        if(diff > max) {
            maxChar = c;
            max = diff;
        }
    }
    return maxChar;
}
```

This is case insensitive. You can tweak it a little to make it case sensitive.

Comment: @MouseEvent: thanks for your suggest.  how can initialize str= str.LowerCase(); maybe is better to change name to variable. Agsin, this code can I put after previous code?

Comment: @Clash Ok fixed it up.

Comment: @MouseEvent: thank you, the algorithm works but I have mine doubts if your code implements ArrayList, I don't see shadow of that.

Comment: @Clash no it doesn't, but this solution is _way_ better. Don't know your professor's requirements, though.

Comment: @MouseEvent: he prefers that I solve the exercise by the only use of the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

In case character set is limited with ANSI, the next approach can be used.

1. Create `int` array if symbol occurrences
2. Increment the array value on every character occurrence using the fact, that character can be casted to integer

Please, see the code below:

```
public static char getMaxFrequencyCharacter(String str) {
    int[] occurrences = new int[255];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        occurrences[str.charAt(i)]++;
    }
    int max = 0;
    char symbol = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < occurrences.length; i++) {
        if (occurrences[i] > max) {
            max = occurrences[i];
            symbol = (char) i;
        }
    }
    return symbol;
}
```

Also note, that there can be several characters with the same max frequency.
In this case you should

1. Find max occurrences number
2. Collect all characters where `occurrences[i] == max`

Answer (score 0):

here is a case-sensitive version

```
    String word = "hello my name is wombat";
    int size = word.length();
    int max = 0;
    char maxChar = 'a';
    for (char x = 'A'; x <= 'z'; x++) {
        word = word.replace(String.valueOf(x), "");
        int newSize = word.length();
        if (size - newSize > max) {
            maxChar = x;
            max = size - newSize;
        }
        size = newSize;
    }

    System.out.println("maxchar is " + maxChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to sort the character-array, and then iterate over it to find the longest stretch of consecutive duplicates:

```
final char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();
java.util.Arrays.sort(charArray);

int maxCount = -1;
char charWithMaxCount = '\0';
int i = 0;
while (i < charArray.length) {
    int j = i;
    while (j < charArray.length && charArray[j] == charArray[i]) {
        ++j;
    }
    if (j - i > maxCount) {
        maxCount = j - i;
        charWithMaxCount = charArray[i];
    }
    i = j;
}

// now charWithMaxCount is the desired result
```